# jQuery selecting div from a set(group) of class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, traversal

My intention is to select all 2nd element from a class. Fade in that div and fadeout all 1st element of that class.

An example like below. When user click next, select all 2nd set of slide-box from modalDialog and fade them in or out accordingly. The jQuery I wrote select the list based on total number of .slide-box class. So only 2nd .slide-box fades in or out. Thanks in advance. Codepen: http://codepen.io/rezasan/pen/LROyqX

HTML:

```
    <a href=""#">NEXT</a>
    <ul class="modalBox">

      <li class="modalDialog">
        <div class="slide-box">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" />
          <p>IMAGE SET 1</p>
          <div class="slide-box">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300/300" />
            <p>IMAGE SET 1</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

     <li class="modalDialog">
        <div class="slide-box">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" />
          <p>IMAGE SET 2</p>
          <div class="slide-box">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300/300" />
            <p>IMAGE SET 2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

       <li class="modalDialog">
        <div class="slide-box">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" />
          <p>IMAGE SET 3</p>
          <div class="slide-box">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300/300" />
            <p>IMAGE SET 3</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
```

jQuery:

```
    var counter = 1;
    //Hide all second element of slide-box
    $(".modalDialog .slide-box:eq("+counter+")").hide();

    //When user click, call rotateImage function
    $('a').click(function(){
      rotateImage();
    });

    //If counter = 1, fade in 2nd image of all sets and fade out 1st image.
    function rotateImage(){
      if(counter === 1){
        $(".modalDialog .slide-box:eq("+counter+")").fadeIn();
      }
    }
```

CSS:

```
    *{
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      text-align:center;
    }

    li{
      margin:20px 0px;
      display:inline-block;
      vertical-align:text-top;
    }
```

Comment: Adding an id might work but is there any other workaround with jquery traversing guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`nth-child()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) or [`nth-of-type()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/) selectors within jQuery to target specific elements at a given interval, especially if you consider making a few modifications to your HTML.

**Consider Not Nesting Your Elements**

Since you want to be able to effectively target each of the boxes individually, it would probably be best not to nest them. Try updating your existing dialogs as follows :

```
<li class="modalDialog">
    <div class="slide-box">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" />
      <p>IMAGE SET 1</p>
    </div>                                        
    <div class="slide-box">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300/300" />
        <p>IMAGE SET 1</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

**Let Your Counter and jQuery Work For You**

By taking advantage of the previous change and the `nth-child()` selector, you can now easily toggle between hiding every even and odd elements by passing `2n` and `2n+1` to the `nth-child()` selector respectively.

This will allow you change your code as such :

```
// Initially hide every 2nd element
$(".modalDialog .slide-box:nth-child(2n)").hide();

$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Update your counter and handle rolling over (toggle between 0 and 1)
    counter = ++counter % 2;
    rotateImage();
});

function rotateImage(){
  // Initally hide all of your boxes
  $('.modalDialog .slide-box').hide();
  // Only show even / odd based on the counter
  $(".modalDialog .slide-box:nth-child(2n +"+counter+")").fadeIn();
}
```

**Putting It All Together**

[image]

```js
var counter = 1;
//Hide all second element of slide-box
$(".modalDialog .slide-box:nth-child(2n)").hide();

//When user click, call rotateImage function
$('a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  counter = ++counter % 2;
  rotateImage();
});

//If counter = 1, fade in 2nd image of all sets and fade out 1st image.
function rotateImage(){
  $('.modalDialog .slide-box').hide();
  $(".modalDialog .slide-box:nth-child(2n +"+counter+")").fadeIn();
}
```

```css
        *{
          margin:0;
          padding:0;
          text-align:center;
        }

        li{
          margin:20px 0px;
          display:inline-block;
          vertical-align:text-top;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href=""#">NEXT</a>
<ul class="modalBox">
  
  <li class="modalDialog">
    <div class="slide-box">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" />
      <p>IMAGE SET 1</p>
    </div>                                        
    <div class="slide-box">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300/300" />
        <p>IMAGE SET 1</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  
 <li class="modalDialog">
    <div class="slide-box">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" />
      <p>IMAGE SET 2</p>
    </div>                                        
    <div class="slide-box">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300/300" />
        <p>IMAGE SET 2</p>
    </div>
  </li>

   <li class="modalDialog">
    <div class="slide-box">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" />
      <p>IMAGE SET 3</p>
    </div>                                        
    <div class="slide-box">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300/300" />
        <p>IMAGE SET 3</p>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

You can also [see an updated version of your original example here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JROJow).

Comment: Thanks Rion for your kind assistance. I didn't think of that. We can use the even odd selector as well. You're a genius!